# How to return catch exception in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, error-handling

I working on error handling of api's. i want if api is crashed then it display a message of "Server is down" something like this, in UI.

I created a class where i'm creating methods of api, here in `getBooks` method if i modify the `api url` then it is printing this `Exception`, and i want it in UI. The problem is `getBooks` return type is `List<Book>>` so we can't return this Exception, any solution how to do this?

```
Exception
E/flutter (12924): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Exception
```

here is my api code

```
class BooksApi {
  static Future<List<Book>> getBooks(String query) async {
    try {
      final url = Uri.parse(
          'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JohannesMilke/d53fbbe9a1b7e7ca2645db13b995dc6f/raw/eace0e20f86cdde3352b2d92f699b6e9dedd8c70/books.json');
      final response = await http.get(url);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List books = json.decode(response.body);

        return books.map((json) => Book.fromJson(json)).where((book) {
          final titleLower = book.title.toLowerCase();
          final authorLower = book.author.toLowerCase();
          final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();

          return titleLower.contains(searchLower) ||
              authorLower.contains(searchLower);
        }).toList();
      } else {
        throw Exception;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("e");
      print(e);
      
       
    }
  
    throw Exception;
  }
}
```

and calling it like

```
Future init() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    var books = await BooksApi.getBooks(query); //this
    
    var response = await obj.getProduct();
    print(response);
    setState(() => this.books = books);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle errors with `then` and `onError` :

```dart
await BooksApi.getBooks(query).then((books) async {
  setState(() => {
    this.books = books;
    this.isLoading = false;
  })
}, onError: (error) {
  // do something with error
});
```

or a simple try-catch (you can write try-catch clauses the same way you would in synchronous code).

See [handling errors](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#handling-errors).

You can also use `catchError` id you don't use `async`/`await` :

```dart
BooksApi.getBooks(query).then((books) { 
  setState(() => {
    this.books = books;
    this.isLoading = false;
  })
}).catchError((error, stackTrace) {
  print("error is: $error");
});
```

See [futures error handling](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling).

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap 'var books = await BooksApi.getBooks(query)' with try and catch.

```
...
try {
   var books = await BooksApi.getBooks(query);
} catch (e) {
   // To do for UI
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For api, you need to make something like this:

```
APIModel{
  final int code;
// or a success flag
// final bool success;
final String message;
final List<Book> data;
APIModel({this.code,this.message,this.data});
}
```

It means, every api have its own `code`,`message`,and `data` filed.
When you request, you can check your `code` or `success`:

```dart
var response = await request(params);
isLoading = false;
if(response.code == 0){}
// or
if(response.success){
  // do what you want
}
else {
 Toast.show(response.message);
}
```

You can use `build_runner` and `json_serializable`.

Comment: Try solve it by design, not by fix.